# Keeping only values that match regex in file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to modify a file using sed in a bash script

The file has a format like:

---

```
asfdsdfad..... : 4.12

aldkfjsadk.... : 3.90

asdlkfjasd.... : 2.33
```

---

I want to modify the file to only contain the numbers, including the decimal.

A regex of what I want to KEEP would be simply `[0-9].[0-9][0-9]`

Currently I have been trying to use `sed s/[regex]//g`
However, I am having trouble finding a correct regex that is the inverse. So either I need to find a correct regex to be the inverse of the above regex, or have a command to keep the regex, instead of remove it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following regex, this will remove everything up until a number.

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]\+//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives...

```
cut -d " " -f 3 file.txt
```

**OR**

```
awk -F " " '{print $3}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{1,\}\.\{0,1\}[0-9]*\) *$/\1/' YourFile
```

Keep only digit followed by a eventualy 1 dot and eventuellay by digits at the end of line (also remove space at the end if any)

Answer (score 1):

This may do:

```
awk '{$0=$3}NF' file
4.12
3.90
2.33
```

It will also remove the blank lines.